# Chamar um método de uma classe interna desde fora

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma classe B e nessa classe necessito chamar um método, `getSomething(type, option)`, que se encontra definido numa classe A que é uma classe que `extends AsyncTask` e que se encontra dentro da classe C.

A minha classe C está definida da seguinte forma:

```
public class C extends BaseActivity{
(...)
 public class A extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 (...)
  public String doInBackground(String... params) {
  (...)
  }
  public String getSomething(String type, String option){
  (...)
  }
  protected void onPreExecute() {
  (...)
  }
  protected void onPostExecute(String result){
  (...)
  }
(...)
}
```

O que estou a tentar fazer é dentro da classe B, dentro de um método colocar esta chamada ao método getSomething():

```
String sentence = new C().new A().getSomething(type,option);
```

também já tentei:

```
new C().new A().execute();
```

Não consigo chamar o método porque me dá excepção

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

sempre que é executada a chamada ao método getSomething(...).

Alguém pode ajudar, para saber como posso chamar o procedimento desde outra classe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para instanciar uma classe interna fora da classe onde foi declarada, é necessário primeiro criar uma instância da classe externa e usar a sintaxe `objectoExterno.new ClasseInterna()` para criar o objecto interno.

```
ClasseExterna objectoExterno = new ClasseExterna();
ClasseExterna.ClasseInterna objectoInterno = objectoExterno.new ClasseInterna();
```

No seu caso, como a classe **C** é uma *Activity*, isso não pode ser feito porque uma *Activity* não deve ser instanciada através do operador `new`.

A solução passa por transformar a classe interna numa classe normal e instanciá-la da forma habitual em cada uma das classes.

Comment: Obrigada. Fiquei esclarecida.

Answer (score 0):

Na classe 'A', crie a instância:

```
public static A a;
```

Agora na sua classe 'B', chame:

```
A.a.getSomething();
```

Não testei se funciona, mas deve funcionar!